# Heroku and Aiohttp - will this cause problems?

Tags: python, heroku

When deploying to Heroku I found this error:

`ERROR: aiohttp 3.7.3 has requirement chardet<4.0,>=2.0, but you'll have chardet 4.0.0 which is incompatible.`

Yet below it says

`Successfully installed aiohttp-3.7.3`

However, the program doesn't seem to be working as intended - it works on my local version but not when I deploy it to heroku which makes me suspect that the ERROR caused problems. How can I change the chardet to be compatible, in this case?

Comment: Are you directly depending on `chardet`? If not, it's a transitive dependency. Are you using `pip` and a `requirements.txt` file? pip-tools? Pipenv and `Pipfile` / `Pipfile.lock`? Poetry and `pyproject.toml`? Something else?

Comment: Actually I'm so stupid I found the logs and it was because of a python 3.7 vs 3.6 thing, the chardet error had no effect